# Insert picture with Selection.PasteSpecial not working

Tags: vba, ms-word

I use this code to insert a picture from the clipboard:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteDeviceIndependentBitmap, Placement:=wdInLine, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

This code is running well with Word 2007 but not with Word 2013. In W07 the picture is copied into the document, with W13 I only get a blank document.

I tried it without the `DataType` (`Selection.PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine`) but still the same.

The picture is correct in the clipboard as shown under "Insert"

[image]

How can I get it work? Thanks

**Update code with selection:**

```
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=2
Selection.Cells.SetWidth ColumnWidth:=CentimetersToPoints(11.5), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
Selection.Rows.SpaceBetweenColumns = CentimetersToPoints(0.25)
Selection.Move Unit:=wdColumn, Count:=1
Selection.SelectColumn
Selection.Cells.SetWidth ColumnWidth:=CentimetersToPoints(4.5), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
Selection.Rows.SpaceBetweenColumns = CentimetersToPoints(0.25)
Selection.SelectColumn
Selection.Cells.HeightRule = wdRowHeightAuto
With Selection.Rows
    .Alignment = wdAlignRowLeft
    .AllowBreakAcrossPages = True
    .SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=CentimetersToPoints(0), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
End With
Selection.Tables(1).Select
Selection.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
Selection.Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
Selection.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
Selection.Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
Selection.Borders(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
Selection.Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteDeviceIndependentBitmap, Placement:=wdInLine, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False

 Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
```

Comment: Word 2013 has some changes in the graphics engine, among other things, so graphics handling is definitely different. I wouldn't expect something to not paste, however... And if you copy/paste this graphic as a user (not with a macro) does it paste? What is the current selection when pasting? The current view?

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for the infos. Yes manually copy & paste works and insert the picture. Pasting is the current view

Comment: OK, so we know that pasting should work. Could you show us more of the code. It's not clear from that single line what the target (Selection) actually is. Selection is always a tricky proposition - possibly the Selection isn't what you expect it to be? You could also try stopping your code before this line, so that you (the end user) are in the target document with the "Selection" and try manually pasting...

Comment: @CindyMeister sry for my late comment. I updated the question with the code for the selection. Stopping the code and manually inserting the picture is successful at the right position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional code helps - and I've edited it to use the Word object model instead of Selection. It should now execute faster, be more predictable and easier to read. What wasn't clear from your code is whether you want to change the column settings for the first or the second column and whether the picture should be in the first or the second cell. If I got it wrong, you can simply change the index numbers (from 1 to 2).

I changed the PasteSpecial to paste into the cell Range (rather than "to" the cell). It might help if the "target" doesn't not contain the cell's structural storage (end-of-cell marker). Give this a try...

```
Dim rngDoc as Word.Range, rngTbl as Word.Range
Dim tbl as Word.Table, col1 as Word.Column
Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.Content
rngDoc.Collapse wdCollapseEnd  'End of the document
Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=rngDoc, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=2
Set rngTbl = tbl.Range
rngTbl.Cells.SetWidth ColumnWidth:=CentimetersToPoints(11.5),
       RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
tbl.Rows.SpaceBetweenColumns = CentimetersToPoints(0.25)
tbl.Columns(1).Cells.SetWidth ColumnWidth:=CentimetersToPoints(4.5), 
       RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
tbl.Columns(1).Cells.HeightRule = wdRowHeightAuto
With tbl.Rows
  .Alignment = wdAlignRowLeft
  .AllowBreakAcrossPages = True
  .SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=CentimetersToPoints(0), 
          RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
End With
With tbl
  .Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
  .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
  .Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
  .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
  .Borders(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
  .Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
End With
Set rng = tbl.Cell(1,1).Range
rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
rng.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteDeviceIndependentBitmap, 
    Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```