# VBA Word Add selected inline shape to a table cell

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an inline shape object selected in Word and am trying to paste it (move it) into a table cell using VBA. But I can't find any API to do the job. I would like to do this

```
// C#
myCell.InlineShapes.Add(selection.InlineShapes[1]);
```

But there are no APIs in VBA or C# that I can find to do that.

I found [this SO link that almost does the job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076102/word-vba-add-inlineshape-object-to-table-cell), but it loads a picture directly from a file into the table cell.

How can I get the selected image into the cell (either in Shapes or InlineShapes)? Thank you

UPDATE:

I found [another example by Cindy Meister here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087603/insert-picture-with-selection-pastespecial-not-working) to give me a hint on the right approach. Thank you, Cindy!!

This code finally worked. I had to go through the clipboard and get the cell range to pull in the picture from the clipboard using PasteSpecial. Weird. But it worked. Maybe there is a better way.

```
// C#
sel.CopyAsPicture();
var cell = table.Cell(row, 1);

// Must use cell.PasteSpecial to pull in the image from the clipboard
var range = cell.Range;
range.PasteSpecial(null, null, WdOLEPlacement.wdInLine, false,
    WdPasteDataType.wdPasteShape);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```vb
Sub MoveShapeToTable()
    Dim ish As InlineShape, tblNew As Table
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ish = Selection.InlineShapes(1)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "No InlineShapes selected", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ish.Range.Cut
    With ActiveDocument
        Set tblNew = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Range.Characters.Last, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=1, _
                     DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior)
        tblNew.Cell(1, 1).Range.Paste
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and clean code (much simpler than ```PasteSpecial```). I confirm that it worked in C#. I used ```sel.Range.Cut();``` and ```cell.Range.Paste();``` with success. It always amazes me how someone can post super-clean code and make it look so easy after my struggles.